# UISearchBar set as titleView acts weird on push segue

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, segue

I have a UISearchBar set to the nav bar's titleView. When I push segue to the next view controller, it fades away to the left correctly. However, when hitting back and returning to the original view it tries to animate it and looks horrible.

Here's a screenshot of the animation happening when I hit back.
[image]

I'm not sure exactly how to get rid of this... any ideas?

Edit: I think it might have to do with the background image of the search bar.

Comment: i just tried it and looks perfect no problem , can you show us your code ?

Comment: I just ended up fixing it! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This somehow fixed it.

```
searchBar.backgroundImage = getImageWithColor(blue, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 50))

func getImageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    var rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    var image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```